# Return either an in-memory (cached) collection, or a task from an async await response

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have a scenario where my service class communicates to an API and populates a list. This method is

```
 public async Task<List<T>> Foo()
```

and in this method I am doing an async await to retrieve data from the API and deserialize to a list.

The thing is, I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (list is cached in memory)
   //serve data from the in memory list
else
   //await get data from the API
```

But the return type in the first part of the if statement is `List<T>` whereas the return type of the second part is `Task<List<T>>`

How can I do this? Can I just have my in-memory list be a Task? (Maybe I can wrap the List in a task)?

Thank you all!

Comment: Just don't `await` the first return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the List inside a Task. Using this code.

```
if (list is cached in memory)
  return Task.FromResult(list);
else
  return await GetResultFromApi();//returns Task<List<T>>
```

Comment: Would be true if he didn't async await inside Foo, but he does, so why bother creating a fake task?

Comment: @grek40 It's not a fake task. If one wants to use memoization or caching inside `Foo` one has to return a *completed* task. In fact, that's one of the reasons `ValueTask` was added in C# 7

Comment: I am sorry I was discussing this with a colleague. My first inside was correct. see @PanagiotisKanavos, I just edited it back.

Comment: You need to do *one or the other*.  By doing both, you're creating the same problem, but in reverse.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going into technical details here, but think about `await` as unwrapping a `Task<T>` into `T` and an `async` method as wrapping its return value `T` into `Task<T>`.

So if your method signature is like you asked

```
public async Task<List<T>> Foo()
```

Then your return value is different from your comment:

```
GetDataFromApi(); // results in Task<List<T>>
await GetDataFromApi(); // results in List<T>
```

So anyway, the `return` statement of an `async Task<List<T>>` expects `List<T>` and not `Task<List<T>>`

```
public async Task<List<T>> Foo()
{
    if (list is cached in memory)
        return list; //serve data from the in memory list
    else
        return await GetDataFromApi(); //await get data from the API
}
```

In case you don't use async await, you can wrap the result in a finished task:

```
public Task<List<T>> Foo()
{
    if (list is cached in memory)
        return Task.FromResult(list); //serve data from the in memory list
    else
        return GetDataFromApi(); //await get data from the API
}
```

Note both, `async` and `await` are removed in this second sample.

Answer (score 3):

I often find `Lazy<T>` to be useful when working with functions that only need to calculate values on the first time being called.

I would consider using Stephen Cleary's `AsyncLazy<T>` from his [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library which is an async version of `Lazy<T>` and great for cached values properties, you can replace your method with a property:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        Foo = new AsyncLazy<List<T>>(async ()=> 
        {
            var data = await GetDataAsync();
            return data;
        });
    }

    public AsyncLazy<List<T>> Foo { get; } 
}
```

And use the property like this:

```
var someClass = /*get SomeClass somehow*/
var foo = await someClass.Foo;
```

More info about async cached values in Stephen Cleary's [Async OOP 3: Properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) blog article.

Comment: (Facepalm) How could I forget about Lazy<T> ?

Comment: The further we stray from the question, the closer we come to a good solution :D

Answer (score 2):

This is called memoization. A function *remembers* previous values so it doesn't have to recalculate them. It's a common technique used in functional languages.

You can create a generic `memoize` function that takes one method and handles caching. This is easy to write in C# 7. In C# 6 you'd have to define a Func variable which is a littel bit uglier :

```
    public Func<TIn, TOut> Memoize<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> f)
    {
        var cache = new Dictionary<TIn, TOut>();
        TOut Run (TIn x)
        {
            if (cache.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                return cache[x];
            }
            var result = f(x);
            cache[x] = result;
            return result;
        }
        return Run;
    }
```

Once you have Memoize, you can convert any function, including any asynchronous function, to a cacheable function, eg:

```
async Task<List<Order>> foo(int customerId)
{
    ..
    var items= await ...;
    return items
}

var cachedFunc=Memoize<int,Task<List<Order>>>(foo);
...
var orders=await cachedFunc(someId);
var sameOrders=await cachedFunc(someId);
Debug.Assert(orders=newOrders);
```

You can simplify the code slightly by creating a `MemoizeAsync` version:

```
    public Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> MemoizeAsync<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> f)
    {
        var cache = new Dictionary<TIn, TOut>();
        async TOut Run (TIn x)
        {
            if (cache.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                return cache[x];
            }
            var result = await f(x);
            cache[x] = result;
            return result;
        }
        return Run;
    }
```

This will create the cached function without specifying a Task in the type list:

```
var cachedFunc=MemoizeAsync<int,List<Order>>(foo);
```

**UPDATE**

That's what you get if you change the post without testing the code. Thanks to Servy for noticing

Storing the task instead of the result can make the code even simpler, without changing the callers:

```
public Func<TIn, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TOut>> MemoizeAsync<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> f)
{
    var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TIn, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TOut>>();
    Task<TOut> Run (TIn x) => cache.GetOrAdd(x, f);         
    return Run;
}
```

In C# 4, the same code would be :

```
public Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> MemoizeAsync<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> f)
{
    var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TIn, Task<TOut>>();
    return x => cache.GetOrAdd(x, f);         
}
```

Memoizing and calling this test function twice, prints out a message only once :

```
Task<string> test(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working");
    return Task.FromResult(x);
}

var cachedFunc=MemoizeAsync<string,string>(test);
var results=await Task.WhenAll(cachedFunc("a"),cachedFunc("a"));
```

This will print :

```
Working
a a
```

Comment: The first part is pretty decent, but since you adress the actual issue of caching, I think keeping the `async` is a bad idea. It will lead to situations where the second call is started before `await f(x)` returns. It's crucial to cache the task even while it is not finished in order to avoid multiple queries. Still a good answer, I got completely carried away by the syntactic issues and didn't really focus the cache implementation part.

Comment: You mean, that someone can call `cachedFun` twice from different threads? That's the only case where the same function, same dictionaries are used. `Memoize` returns a new fuction with its own cache. The `Async` version can be made thread-safe and even simpler, with a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Depending on the internals it's actually enough not to `await` the `cachedFun(someId)` call before issuing the second one... like when someone decides to optimize by doing `var t1 = cachedFun(someId); var t2 = cachedFun(sometimesSameId); await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);`

Comment: @grek40 you mean caching the task, not its result. You'd still need the ConcurrentDictionary to avoid creating two tasks. The `async/await` keyword can be removed if `cache` is a `new ConcurrentDictionary<TIn, Task<TOut>>`. Calling code doesn't have to change

Comment: You shouldn't have 5 different broken versions of the code with a working version at the end.  Just have a working version.

Comment: incidentally the C# 4.0 solution using lambdas comes out *simpler* than using a local function.  It can simply be `var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TIn, Task<TOut>>(); return key => cache.GetOrAdd(key, f);`  You're also creating the value of the dictionary every single time when you shouldn't be (the whole point of the exercise is to avoid it, and you're not doing that).

Comment: #Servy Ooops. That's why one shouldn't make important changes in the SO post without testing

Comment: @Servy using a local method looks the same but doesn't allocate a delegate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But then returning it as a delegate allocates a delegate, putting you in exactly the same spot.  If you were only ever calling the method from inside the containing method, then yes, that would be the case.